# How to compare multiple rows between two different worksheets in excel 2010?

Tags: arrays, vba, loops, compare, range

Worksheet 1 (This year):

```
Name       Birthday     Grade 1 Grade 2 Grade 3  

AAA        dd/mm/yyyy      B       A      B
BBB        dd1/mm/yyyy     A       B      C
CCC        dd/mm/yyyy      B       C      D
DDD        dd/mm/yyyy      C       D      C
```

Worksheet 2 (Last year):

```
Name       Birthday     Grade 1 Grade 2 Grade 3   

BBB        dd/mm/yyyy      B       B      B
AAA        dd/mm/yyyy      A       A      A
DDD        dd/mm/yyyy      D       D      D
CCC        dd/mm/yyyy      C       C      C
```

I need to check the marks and birthday of all students and compare those information of both years. 
(Birthday of the student will not be changed, but I need to verify if the birthday record is consistent or not)

I hope I can get the results like below, How do i achieve this?

[image]

-------------------------------------------------- Updated on 31 Dec -------------------------------------------------------

Thanks for the code from "RAJA THEVAR", the two worksheets can be compared.

Actually three (3) date entries and twelve (12) grade entries will be compared.

I modified the code and found it becomes a bit lengthy. I hope it can be simplified by using some loops, array, etc.

Is there a way to do that?

Option Explicit

```
Sub Test()

Dim thisyearlstr As Integer

Dim Lastyearlstr As Integer

Dim Resultlstr As Integer


Dim thisyearbday As String

Dim Lastyearbday As String

Dim thisyrAday As String

Dim lastyrAday As String

Dim thisyrRday As String

Dim lastyrRday As String


Dim thisyearg1 As String

Dim thisyearg2 As String

Dim thisyearg3 As String

Dim thisyearg4 As String

Dim thisyearg5 As String

Dim thisyearg6 As String

Dim thisyearg7 As String

Dim thisyearg8 As String

Dim thisyearg9 As String

Dim thisyearg10 As String

Dim thisyearg11 As String

Dim thisyearg12 As String


Dim lastyearg1 As String

Dim lastyearg2 As String

Dim lastyearg3 As String

Dim lastyearg4 As String

Dim lastyearg5 As String

Dim lastyearg6 As String

Dim lastyearg7 As String

Dim lastyearg8 As String

Dim lastyearg9 As String

Dim lastyearg10 As String

Dim lastyearg11 As String

Dim lastyearg12 As String

Dim i As Integer

Dim lookup As String ' name under check

Dim grade1 As Integer

Dim grade2 As Integer

Dim grade3 As Integer

Dim grade4 As Integer

Dim grade5 As Integer

Dim grade6 As Integer

Dim grade7 As Integer

Dim grade8 As Integer

Dim grade9 As Integer

Dim grade10 As Integer

Dim grade11 As Integer

Dim grade12 As Integer

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Activate
Cells.Select

Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

' Writing labels to first row
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("A1").Value = "Name"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("B1").Value = "Birthday"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("C1").Value = "AppDay"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("D1").Value = "RankDay"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("E1").Value = "Grade 1"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("F1").Value = "Grade 2"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("G1").Value = "Grade 3"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("H1").Value = "Grade 4"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("I1").Value = "Grade 5"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("J1").Value = "Grade 6"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("K1").Value = "Grade 7"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("L1").Value = "Grade 8"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("M1").Value = "Grade 9"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("N1").Value = "Grade 10"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("O1").Value = "Grade 11"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("P1").Value = "Grade 12"

Resultlstr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Row + 1

thisyearlstr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Row

Lastyearlstr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Last year").Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Row

' Copy all names in "This year" to "Result" Worksheet
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A2:A" & thisyearlstr).Copy

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("A" & Resultlstr).PasteSpecial

Resultlstr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To Resultlstr

lookup = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("A" & i).Value ' lookup = name under check

thisyearbday = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A:B"), 2, 0) ' store B-day of the name under check

thisyrAday = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A:C"), 3, 0)

thisyrRday = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A:D"), 4, 0)

Lastyearbday = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("last year").Range("A:B"), 2, 0)

lastyrAday = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("last year").Range("A:C"), 3, 0)

lastyrRday = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("last year").Range("A:D"), 4, 0)


thisyearg1 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A:E"), 5, 0)

thisyearg2 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A:F"), 6, 0)

thisyearg3 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A:G"), 7, 0)

thisyearg4 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A:H"), 8, 0)

thisyearg5 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A:I"), 9, 0)

thisyearg6 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A:J"), 10, 0)

thisyearg7 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A:K"), 11, 0)

thisyearg8 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A:L"), 12, 0)

thisyearg9 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A:M"), 13, 0)

thisyearg10 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A:N"), 14, 0)

thisyearg11 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A:O"), 15, 0)

thisyearg12 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A:P"), 16, 0)


lastyearg1 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Last year").Range("A:E"), 5, 0)

lastyearg2 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Last year").Range("A:F"), 6, 0)

lastyearg3 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Last year").Range("A:G"), 7, 0)

lastyearg4 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Last year").Range("A:H"), 8, 0)

lastyearg5 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Last year").Range("A:I"), 9, 0)

lastyearg6 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Last year").Range("A:J"), 10, 0)

lastyearg7 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Last year").Range("A:K"), 11, 0)

lastyearg8 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Last year").Range("A:L"), 12, 0)

lastyearg9 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Last year").Range("A:M"), 13, 0)

lastyearg10 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Last year").Range("A:N"), 14, 0)

lastyearg11 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Last year").Range("A:O"), 15, 0)

lastyearg12 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Last year").Range("A:P"), 16, 0)


ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("B" & i).Value = thisyearbday ' writing stored data to "Result" worksheet
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("C" & i).Value = thisyrAday
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("D" & i).Value = thisyrRday
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("E" & i).Value = thisyearg1
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("F" & i).Value = thisyearg2
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("G" & i).Value = thisyearg3
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("H" & i).Value = thisyearg4
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("I" & i).Value = thisyearg5
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("J" & i).Value = thisyearg6
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("K" & i).Value = thisyearg7
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("L" & i).Value = thisyearg8
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("M" & i).Value = thisyearg9
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("N" & i).Value = thisyearg10
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("O" & i).Value = thisyearg11
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("P" & i).Value = thisyearg12

' Determine if b-day entries in two worksheets are the same
   If thisyearbday = Lastyearbday Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("B" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
   Else
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("B" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(204, 192, 218)
   End If

   If thisyrAday = lastyrAday Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("C" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
   Else
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("C" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(204, 192, 218)
   End If

   If thisyrRday = lastyrRday Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("D" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
   Else
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("D" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(204, 192, 218)
   End If

   grade1 = Comparegrade(thisyearg1, lastyearg1)
   If grade1 = 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("E" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
   ElseIf grade1 < 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("E" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(230, 184, 183)
   ElseIf grade1 > 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("E" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(216, 228, 188)
   End If


   grade2 = Comparegrade(thisyearg2, lastyearg2)
   If grade2 = 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("F" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
   ElseIf grade2 < 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("F" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(230, 184, 183)
   ElseIf grade2 > 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("F" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(216, 228, 188)
   End If

   grade3 = Comparegrade(thisyearg3, lastyearg3)
   If grade3 = 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("G" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
   ElseIf grade3 < 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("G" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(230, 184, 183)
   ElseIf grade3 > 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("G" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(216, 228, 188)
   End If

   grade4 = Comparegrade(thisyearg4, lastyearg4)
   If grade4 = 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("H" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
   ElseIf grade4 < 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("H" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(230, 184, 183)
   ElseIf grade4 > 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("H" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(216, 228, 188)
   End If

   grade5 = Comparegrade(thisyearg5, lastyearg5)
   If grade5 = 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("I" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
   ElseIf grade5 < 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("I" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(230, 184, 183)
   ElseIf grade5 > 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("I" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(216, 228, 188)
   End If

   grade6 = Comparegrade(thisyearg6, lastyearg6)
   If grade6 = 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("J" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
   ElseIf grade6 < 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("J" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(230, 184, 183)
   ElseIf grade6 > 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("J" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(216, 228, 188)
   End If

   grade7 = Comparegrade(thisyearg7, lastyearg7)
   If grade7 = 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("K" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
   ElseIf grade7 < 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("K" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(230, 184, 183)
   ElseIf grade7 > 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("K" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(216, 228, 188)
   End If

   grade8 = Comparegrade(thisyearg8, lastyearg8)
   If grade8 = 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("L" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
   ElseIf grade8 < 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("L" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(230, 184, 183)
   ElseIf grade8 > 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("L" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(216, 228, 188)
   End If

   grade9 = Comparegrade(thisyearg9, lastyearg9)
   If grade9 = 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("M" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
   ElseIf grade9 < 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("M" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(230, 184, 183)
   ElseIf grade9 > 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("M" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(216, 228, 188)
   End If

   grade10 = Comparegrade(thisyearg10, lastyearg10)
   If grade10 = 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("N" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
   ElseIf grade10 < 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("N" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(230, 184, 183)
   ElseIf grade10 > 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("N" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(216, 228, 188)
   End If

   grade11 = Comparegrade(thisyearg11, lastyearg11)
   If grade11 = 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("O" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
   ElseIf grade11 < 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("O" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(230, 184, 183)
   ElseIf grade11 > 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("O" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(216, 228, 188)
   End If

   grade12 = Comparegrade(thisyearg12, lastyearg12)
   If grade12 = 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("P" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
   ElseIf grade12 < 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("P" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(230, 184, 183)
   ElseIf grade12 > 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("P" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(216, 228, 188)
   End If

Next


End Sub

Function Comparegrade(grade1, grade2)

If UCase(grade1) = "A" Then
grade1 = 4
ElseIf UCase(grade1) = "B" Then
grade1 = 3
ElseIf UCase(grade1) = "C" Then
grade1 = 2
ElseIf UCase(grade1) = "D" Then
grade1 = 1
End If

If UCase(grade2) = "A" Then
grade2 = 4
ElseIf UCase(grade2) = "B" Then
grade2 = 3
ElseIf UCase(grade2) = "C" Then
grade2 = 2
ElseIf UCase(grade2) = "D" Then
grade2 = 1
End If

Comparegrade = grade1 - grade2
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following code.

```
Option Explicit

    Sub Test()

    Dim thisyearlstr As Integer

    Dim Lastyearlstr As Integer

    Dim Resultlstr As Integer

    Dim thisyearbday As String

    Dim Lastyearbday As String

    Dim thisyearg1 As String

    Dim thisyearg2 As String

    Dim thisyearg3 As String

    Dim lastyearg1 As String

    Dim lastyearg2 As String

    Dim lastyearg3 As String

    Dim i As Integer

    Dim lookup As String

    Dim grade1 As Integer

    Dim grade2 As Integer

    Dim grade3 As Integer

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Activate
    Cells.Select

    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("A1").Value = "Name"

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("B1").Value = "Birthday"

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("C1").Value = "Grade 1"

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("D1").Value = "Grade 2"

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("E1").Value = "Grade 3"

    Resultlstr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    thisyearlstr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Row

    Lastyearlstr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Last year").Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Row

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A2:A" & thisyearlstr).Copy

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("A" & Resultlstr).PasteSpecial

    Resultlstr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To Resultlstr

    lookup = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("A" & i).Value

     thisyearbday = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A:B"), 2, 0)

    Lastyearbday = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("last year").Range("A:B"), 2, 0)


    thisyearg1 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A:C"), 3, 0)


     thisyearg2 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A:D"), 4, 0)

     thisyearg3 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A:E"), 5, 0)

    lastyearg1 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("last year").Range("A:C"), 3, 0)


     lastyearg2 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("last year").Range("A:D"), 4, 0)

     lastyearg3 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("last year").Range("A:E"), 5, 0)

         ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("B" & i).Value = thisyearbday
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("C" & i).Value = thisyearg1
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("D" & i).Value = thisyearg2
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("E" & i).Value = thisyearg3

       If thisyearbday = Lastyearbday Then
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("B" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
       Else
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("B" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(204, 192, 218)
       End If
       grade1 = Comparegrade(thisyearg1, lastyearg1)
       If grade1 = 0 Then
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("C" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
       ElseIf grade1 < 0 Then
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("C" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(230, 184, 183)
       ElseIf grade1 > 0 Then
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("C" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(216, 228, 188)
       End If


      grade2 = Comparegrade(thisyearg2, lastyearg2)
       If grade2 = 0 Then
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("D" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
       ElseIf grade2 < 0 Then
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("D" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(230, 184, 183)
       ElseIf grade2 > 0 Then
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("D" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(216, 228, 188)
       End If
       grade3 = Comparegrade(thisyearg3, lastyearg3)
       If grade3 = 0 Then
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("E" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
       ElseIf grade3 < 0 Then
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("E" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(230, 184, 183)
       ElseIf grade3 > 0 Then
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("E" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(216, 228, 188)
       End If

    Next


    End Sub

    Function Comparegrade(grade1, grade2)

    If UCase(grade1) = "A" Then
    grade1 = 4


    ElseIf UCase(grade1) = "B" Then
    grade1 = 3


    ElseIf UCase(grade1) = "C" Then
    grade1 = 2



    ElseIf UCase(grade1) = "D" Then
    grade1 = 1

    End If

    If UCase(grade2) = "A" Then
    grade2 = 4


    ElseIf UCase(grade2) = "B" Then
    grade2 = 3


    ElseIf UCase(grade2) = "C" Then
    grade2 = 2

    ElseIf UCase(grade2) = "D" Then
    grade2 = 1

    End If

    Comparegrade = grade1 - grade2
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try The following code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim thisyearlstr As Integer

Dim Lastyearlstr As Integer

Dim Resultlstr As Integer


Dim thisyearbday As String

Dim Lastyearbday As String

Dim thisyrAday As String

Dim lastyrAday As String

Dim thisyrRday As String

Dim lastyrRday As String


Dim thisyearg As String

Dim lastyearg As String


Dim i As Integer

Dim lookup As String ' name under check

Dim grade1 As Integer

Dim grade2 As Integer


ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Activate
Cells.Select

Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

' Writing labels to first row
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("A1").Value = "Name"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("B1").Value = "Birthday"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("C1").Value = "AppDay"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("D1").Value = "RankDay"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("E1").Value = "Grade 1"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("F1").Value = "Grade 2"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("G1").Value = "Grade 3"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("H1").Value = "Grade 4"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("I1").Value = "Grade 5"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("J1").Value = "Grade 6"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("K1").Value = "Grade 7"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("L1").Value = "Grade 8"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("M1").Value = "Grade 9"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("N1").Value = "Grade 10"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("O1").Value = "Grade 11"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("P1").Value = "Grade 12"

Resultlstr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Row + 1

thisyearlstr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Row

Lastyearlstr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Last year").Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Row

' Copy all names in "This year" to "Result" Worksheet
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A2:A" & thisyearlstr).Copy

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("A" & Resultlstr).PasteSpecial

Resultlstr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To Resultlstr

lookup = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("A" & i).Value ' lookup = name under check

thisyearbday = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A:B"), 2, 0) ' store B-day of the name under check

thisyrAday = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A:C"), 3, 0)

thisyrRday = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A:D"), 4, 0)

Lastyearbday = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("last year").Range("A:B"), 2, 0)

lastyrAday = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("last year").Range("A:C"), 3, 0)

lastyrRday = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("last year").Range("A:D"), 4, 0)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("B" & i).Value = thisyearbday ' writing stored data to "Result" worksheet
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("C" & i).Value = thisyrAday
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("D" & i).Value = thisyrRday




' Determine if b-day entries in two worksheets are the same
   If thisyearbday = Lastyearbday Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("B" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
   Else
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("B" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(204, 192, 218)
   End If

   If thisyrAday = lastyrAday Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("C" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
   Else
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("C" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(204, 192, 218)
   End If

   If thisyrRday = lastyrRday Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("D" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
   Else
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Range("D" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(204, 192, 218)
   End If


    For j = 5 To 16
    grade = ""
thisyearg = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("This year").Range("A:P"), j, 0)

lastyearg = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Last year").Range("A:P"), j, 0)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Cells(i, j).Value = thisyearg

grade = Comparegrade(thisyearg, lastyearg)

  If grade = 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
   ElseIf grade1 < 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(230, 184, 183)
   ElseIf grade1 > 0 Then
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(216, 228, 188)
End If

Next      

Next


End Sub

Function Comparegrade(grade1, grade2)

If UCase(grade1) = "A" Then
grade1 = 4
ElseIf UCase(grade1) = "B" Then
grade1 = 3
ElseIf UCase(grade1) = "C" Then
grade1 = 2
ElseIf UCase(grade1) = "D" Then
grade1 = 1
End If

If UCase(grade2) = "A" Then
grade2 = 4
ElseIf UCase(grade2) = "B" Then
grade2 = 3
ElseIf UCase(grade2) = "C" Then
grade2 = 2
ElseIf UCase(grade2) = "D" Then
grade2 = 1
End If

Comparegrade = grade1 - grade2
End Function
```